# Adding Captcha in Registration Form using Ajax , Jquery or JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4

Iam writing code for Registration page in Jquery, when i came to using devexpress captcha in registration page, that one is not validating from jquery.so, i replacing captcha to jquery captcha. can any one help me how to write the captcha in Jquery.

Comment: You should really validate captcha on the server and not in JavaScript.  An attacker can easily bypass such client-side validation by replacing the validation script on the client side.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a nice library I use in MVC called reCAPTCHA plugin for .NET: https://code.google.com/p/recaptcha/

There is a Nuget package available for it. Nuget id: recaptcha current verion 1.0.5.0

Now to use it: in your View

Inside your view above or bellow your Submit button:  You add this code:

```
<p>
    @Html.Raw(@Html.GenerateCaptcha())
    @Html.ValidationMessage("captcha")
</p>
```

Then in your controller action add the `RecaptchaControlMvc.CaptchaValidator` attribute and also add an addition bool paramater for the recapccha e.g. captchaValid

```
HttpPost, RecaptchaControlMvc.CaptchaValidator]
[OutputCache(NoStore = true, Duration = 0, VaryByParam = "None")]
public ActionResult Register(RegistrationViewModel model, bool captchaValid)
{
      // If the bool is true The Recapcha validation was successful.
     // If not then you can add a model error with the property name for the: `@Html.ValidationMessage("captcha")`
      if (!isLoan && !captchaValid)
      {
        ModelState.AddModelError("captcha", "Verification word is incorrect. Try again.");
      }

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
           // go an ddo your registration or login
        }
        else
        {
              // handle errors and other messages


        }
        return View(model);
}
```

The Library will take care of the rest.